# What does the word "Star" in "Star Wars" refer to?

Tags: star-wars, title

I wonder what the word "Star" in *Star Wars* refers to. Why did George Lucas choose this title for his epic? The word "Wars" is clear, but I don't know what "Star" refers to. Does anyone know?

Comment: Space, I guess.

Comment: It fits the graphic design better than Space Wars [leaves one letter hanging] or Universe Wars/Galaxy Wars... for similar reasons... & it's punchy, to the point, no room for argument, all-encompassing, obvious, open to any plot-line, timeless...

Comment: Planets also revolve around stars so Star Wars are about the wars taking place on and across a specific galaxy of planets and/or solar systems. I also think it was to convey the sense of adventure, inspiration, and wisdom, as we often say, 'look to or reach for the stars' It also points out the light and dark motif, which is at the center of Skywalker Saga's epic and views on the force.

Comment: @Tetsujin, perhaps he'd prefer it was called Spaceballs...

Comment: Because it's easy on the tongue probably, or it would've been space wars or stars wars.

Comment: Why is the word “wars” clear to you? There are no wars in the films.

Comment: @Mouvier, it's a weird question, no wars in the films!?! Regardless of small fights between empire forces and the rebelliions. Death Star Assault (New Hope). Battle of Hoth (The Empire Strikes Back). Battle of Endor and final great war to destory Death Star and the empire (Returen of the Jedi). The Gungans fight with Droid Army (The Phantom Menace). Battle of Clones, Jedi with droids and the separatists (Attack of Clones). Battle Of Coruscant and fianl purging of the Jedi and opposition of the Empire by the clones.

Comment: Those are not wars but rebellion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case it's not clear, a **star** (in this context) is:

> 1. Any small luminous dot appearing in the cloudless portion of the night sky, especially with a fixed location relative to other such dots.
> 2. (astronomy) A luminous celestial body, made up of plasma (particularly hydrogen and helium) and having a spherical shape. Depending on context the sun may or may not be included.

<sup>[Source: Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/star#Noun)</sup>

The literal meaning of the title could be interpreted as "A series of wars among the **stars**". "Among the stars" is a turn of phrase used to mean "out in space".

Compare with the title *Star Trek*, which means "a journey (trek) among the stars".

Also compare with the TV show *Star Search*, which means "a search for stars". In this case, "stars" means people who will become famous, not large balls of hydrogen fusion in space, but the grammar of the title is the same.

In general, an English construction of *noun verb* often means, "doing *verb* in the context of *noun*". For example, *sea trade* is the trading of goods using ocean vessels. *Shore leave* means "a break from service that takes place on dry land (not at sea)". *Space walk* means "an excursion from a spacecraft wearing only a spacesuit or *EVA suit*" - in other words, "a walk in space".

If that doesn't clarify things enough, you might want to ask your question on the [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The idea you told was the thing I guessed and it could be right. "Stars" may refer to important people who are heroes and villains in both good and evil sides. like the stars or superstars when we talk about famous celebrities.

Comment: Star meaning leading character is not the intended meaning at all.  It refers to stellar, celestial objects.

Answer (score 1):

While Todd Wilcox' answer is true in the literal sense that *[Star Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars)* refers to the wars happening across the galaxy on planets and in outer space, it also refers to both a metaphorical (prominent heroes and villains) and metaphysical (power coming from elsewhere) definition.

> Star Wars is an American **epic space-opera** media franchise created by
> George Lucas. The franchise began with the eponymous 1977 film and
> quickly became a worldwide pop-culture phenomenon.

*Star Wars*, especially the Skywalker family Saga (Epsiodes I-IX) is about "iconic" Heroes and Villains who are featured in this particular story, as the story itself asks, *what does "legacy" mean? What information can we pass on?*

> [Epic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_film) films are a style of film-making with large scale, sweeping scope,
> and spectacle. The usage of the term has shifted over time, sometimes
> designating a film genre and at other times simply synonymous with
> big-budget filmmaking. **Like epics in the classical literary sense it
> is often focused on a heroic character.** An epic's ambitious nature
> helps to set it apart from other types of film such as the period
> piece or adventure film.

To expound on that, because the work is also a "Fantasy Epic", there is also a metaphysical energy, The Force, that is believed to connect all life together, but some are born "Force Sensitive" and can tap into this energy and kinetically use it.

> Star Wars features elements such as knighthood, chivalry, and
> archetypes related to the fantasy genre. The Star Wars galaxy,
> unlike science fiction that features sleek and futuristic settings, is
> portrayed as dirty and grimy in Lucas's concept of a "used
> future". Lucas made a conscious effort to parallel scenes and
> dialogue between films, and especially the journey of Anakin Skywalker
> in the prequels with that of his son Luke. **He has collectively
> referred to the first six episodic films as "the tragedy of Darth
> Vader," and said that the theme of the saga is redemption**.[196]
>
> The final scene in The Last Jedi **depicts servant children playing with
> a toy of Luke Skywalker, and one boy using the Force to grab a broom.
> According to Inverse, this symbolizes that "the Force can be found in
> people with humble beginnings.**"

In the first two trilogies of the Skywalker Saga the general tenor of 'good vs evil' comes from light side and dark side "force users" referred to as the Jedi and Sith. The first trilogy sees the rise and fall of Anakin Skywalker that is echoed in the downfall of the Republic and the Jedi Order, juxtaposing the rise of The Empire and birth of Darth Vader through the Sith Lord, Darth Sidious or Emperor Palpatine.

In the next trilogy the twin children of the Anakin Skywalker must attempt to restore order to the galaxy, as Anakin's son Luke learns the ways of the fallen Jedi in order to confront his father, whose now a destructive Sith Lord.

> ### **[EMPIRE](https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/star-wars-last-jedi-10-revelations-director-rian-johnson/) - Rian Johnson Interview**
>
> "He's taken himself out of the fight, he's sitting on that island in
> exile. I know the Luke I grew up with is not a coward, he's not
> sitting out there hiding, so I had to come up with a reason he was
> there that was active and positive, and something I could genuinely
> believe I could think in his shoes," says Johnson. "And the thing that
> came to me that seemed to make sense to me **is this notion that he
> seems this hero worship of him and of the Jedi that is detrimental to
> the galaxy. The universe has put its faith in its false god of the
> Jedi and they need to forget the religion so they can get back to god,
> that light can rise from a worthier source.** And because he's the last
> Jedi and a symbol of that, it then becomes this self-sacrifice he has
> to do to take himself out of it when he knows his friends are dying,
> when he knows the thing he'd like to do is get back in the fight. He's
> taken the weight of the world on his shoulders by taking himself out
> of the equation so that the Jedi can die out. **The end of the movie is
> him embracing the part of the past that the present needs, which right
> now is the legend of Luke Skywalker, they need something to believe
> in, they need that action figure of Luke Skywalker to grab on to, that
> inspiration to stare up at the stars and believe that you can be a
> hero."**
>
> "I wanted Luke's death to be peaceful, to be on his terms I wanted it
> to be a victory. **I wanted it to be that he's done this huge grand act
> that has restored the spark of hope to the galaxy.** I'm hesitant to put
> into words what he does in the end, but it is completed."

In the last trilogy, the Republic was restored, but fell pray to the Empire turning into the New Order, where Darth Vader's grandson, who claims not to be Sith, eventually comes to power leaning into the dark side. But it is his Uncle, Luke Skywalker's legacy and his possible feelings for an outsider named Rey, that threatens the success of The New Order quashing the resistance once and for all, but Luke sacrifices himself and stories about his bravery and honor are spread across the galaxy inspiring a whole new generation of people to join nearly defeated resistance, aka the "Spark of Hope"! (We have to wait and see how the last episode plays out to know more.)

### *"May the Force be With You."*

In addition, through out these works and in other works, including *Star Wars Rebels*, the notion of what [The Force](https://www.starwars.com/databank/the-force) is and how one should use it (methodology/applied philosophy) is debated, but in many cases there is evidence that the Force does in fact exist and have a "will" and therefor there is an additional mysterious element of fate at work (some Force Users may be able to see the future), which gives ***Star** Wars* philosophical and/or spiritual meaning, as the Force is coming from within and *beyond* the self; a metaphorical definition playing on "stars" as in information coming from somewhere else, like from "God" or the "The Heavens"...

Comment: Come on.  “Star” does not mean hero, it means “actor in a Hollywood movie”.   Can you name one real-life hero in our society that you’d refer to as a “star”?

Comment: Not true, there are "rising stars" in Star Wars rebellions, resistance, Empire, etc "in-universe" meaning that it can refer to ANYONE who is famous or iconic, as their reality does not keep them from the construct of "political recognition", which any EPIC would heavily rely on. Luke's Skywalkers "legacy" (a well known person whose stories about them are spread to others) is what saves the resistance at the end of the Last Jedi. It's thematic to the whole 'Skywalker' legacy and is major a plot point.

Comment: @whiskeychief sure, Barack Obama, Martin Luther King Jr, Amelia Airheart, Rosa Parks, Bono, David Bowie, etc/ While it may be true culturally we don't often refer to athletes, musicians (Rock STARS), politicians, inventors, and rights activists as "stars" (meaning famous heros), the truth is some do and you can: https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2018/12/how-rising-political-stars-31-years-ago-fared/578398/

Comment: Also there is a Star Wars book titled, Lost Stars, which refers to a doomed romance between two leading characters who ended up on opposite sides (rebellion/empire) thus "stars" referring to the main characters while debating notion of being "star-crossed". It also refers to military locations and weapons such as "Star" Destroyers and the second Death "Star".